# How does the output of the following code change if i change f from int to double?

Tags: java

```
int f=1;  //this is to store factorial value
double s=1;
for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
   f=f*i;    //Even though i is int,changing f from int value to double value brigs a difference
   s=s+(double)(1/f);
}
System.out.println(s);
```

I have to find factorial of a number. What I found is that in the above code, if I change f from int to `double`, my answer is in decimal value but if I use `int`, my answer does not come to decimals.
Like in case of int - 2.0 in case of double - 2.718281 as `f` is only multiplying `int` values, from where do the decimal values come?

Comment: not sure question is.  You are outputting s not f.  and you are outputting outside for loop.  Please explain what you expect to see with s.

Answer (score 0):

Thats beacause if ***f*** is a ***double***, the result from its operation with ***s*** `(s = s + 1 / f;)` will return a ***double*** value, and if its an ***int*** it will return its ***int*** value (truncated).

Take a look at this [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.4)

Comment: Actually, the `int` result is *truncated*, not rounded. ie `2 / 3 == 0`

Comment: But if i is int,that means all that f is getting is- 1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian for the comment

Answer (score 0):

Because `1/f` is always 0 except in the first case.

put another system.out inside you for:

```
        int f=1;  //this is to store factorial value
    double s=1;
    for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
        f=f*i;    //Even though i is int,changing f from int value to double value brigs a difference
        System.out.println(1/f);

        s=s+(double)(1/f);
    }
    System.out.println(s);
```

If you change `f` in double value all `1/f` should return a real double value without truncate it.

Answer (score 0):

The catch lies in this expression:-

```
s=s+(double)(1/f);
```

Here, when `f` is a `double`, `1/f` returns a double value. When `f` is an `int`, the value `1/f` is also an `int`. *For Example*: -

```
1/2.0 -> gives 0.5
1/2   -> gives 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In java the result is a double if at-least one among the numerator and denominator is a double. Here in this case numerator (1) is an int is an so 1/f would be an int if f is an int and 1/f would be a double if f is a double.

In case f is an int:

for iteration 1 ie i=1

`s=s+double(1/f) will be s=1.0+double(1/1) -> s=1.0+double(1) -> s=1+1.0 -> s->2.0`

for iteration 2 ie i=2 and now s=2.0

`s=s+double(1/f) will be s=2.0+double(1/2)`

1/2 = 0 because int divided by int will be an int

`s=2.0+double(0)`

Now the integer 0 is typecasted to double. So it becomes

`s=2.0+0.0 -> s=2.0`

Similarly this happens for all the remaining iterations. 1/f is always zero when f is an int greater than 1

In case f is a double

for iteration 1 ie i=1

`s=s+double(1/f) will be s=1.0+double(1/1.0) -> s=1.0+double(1.0) -> s=1.0+1.0 -> s->2.0`

Here the typecast double is not needed because int/double in java already results in a double

for iteration 2 ie i=1 and now s=2.0

`s=s+double(1/f) will be s=2.0+double(1/2.0)`

1/2 = 0.5 because int divided by double will be a double and decimal is not lost

`-> s=2.0+double(0.5) -> s=2.5`

Again the typecast to double is unnecessary.

Similarly the decimal part is not lost in all other iterations when you use a double.

Hence you see a difference when f is a float and f is an int

Answer (score 0):

In the case of int **(1/f)** return only the quotient part but in the case of double, it will return a decimal value. For example, if the value of **f** is 2.

In the case of int (1/2) will give 0.

In the case of double (1/2.0) will give 0.5.